# Dependencies between static library subdirectories and include paths

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, dependency-management

I am working on a project that is to be made of one executable linking with two libraries.
I'm making frequent chages to all of them and don't wish to go though a `sudo make install` cycle for `libA` and `libB`, so I have laid them out in the following fashion:

```
myProject
├── libA
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   │   └── libA
│   │       └── *.h
│   └── src
│       └── *.cpp
│
├── libB
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   │   └── libB
│   │       └── *.h
│   └── src
│       └── *.cpp
│
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── *.h
└── src
    └── *.cpp
```

I'm using CMake subdirectories to automatically link in `libA` and `libB` into `myProject`, and it works fine. The `CMakeList.txt`s are set up as follows:

```
# myProject/CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(myProject)

add_subdirectory(libA)
add_subdirectory(libB)

# Compiler flags, listing of the source files into ${SOURCE_FILES}, etc.

add_executable(myProject ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(myProject libA libB)
```

---

```
# myProject/libA/CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(libA)

# Compiler flags, listing of the source files into ${SOURCE_FILES}, etc.

add_library(libA STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_include_directories(libA PUBLIC include)

install(
    TARGETS libA
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
)

install(
    DIRECTORY include/glk
    DESTINATION include
)
```

`myProject/libB/CMakeLists.txt` is similar.

Now here's the issue: `libB` has a dependency on `libA`, and includes `libA`'s headers through `#include <libA/foo.h>`, and will need symbols from `libA` upon linking (though I guess that's a non-issue with static libraries).

How can I set up this dependency correctly so that `libB` finds everything it needs about this local `libA`, ideally by modifying only `myProject`'s configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a link dependency of `libB` on `libA`. Yes, they might be static libraries, but CMake allows you to specify that you link one library to another even if they are static. Where the libraries are static, such a link relationship is then only used for providing transitive dependencies between the targets (i.e. those provided as PUBLIC or INTERFACE items in the various `target_...` commands). So I'd expect your `libB`'s CMakeLists.txt to look similar to `libA`', except you'd also add the following line:

```
target_link_library(libB PRIVATE libA)
```

Or if `libB` uses parts of `libA` in its own public API, make the above link dependency PUBLIC rather than PRIVATE. By doing this, anywhere that you have a target link against `libB`, CMake will ensure that `libA` appears after it on the final command line. In your example, the top level CMakeLists.txt file links `libB` after `libA`, so without the above `target_link_library()` relationship, the linker would complain about symbols from `libA` being missing, even though `libA` would have been on the linker command line, just in the wrong order. Your syntax for `target_link_libraries()` in your top level CMakeLists.txt files is also incorrect (presumably just a typo in your example). Arguments should not be comma-separated.

The other effect of explicitly linking `libB` to `libA` is that now `libB` picks up PUBLIC and INTERFACE properties from `libA`, which in this case will be the header search path that `libA` defines. You should find that `libB` will now find `libA`'s headers too.